# Paper vs real life analysis of a system

Tags: control-engineering, systems-engineering

Lets say this is the block diagram of a system:

[image]

$K$ is the microcontroller.However in real life applications information doesnt travel instateneously , the output isnt fed back to the input instateneously so shouldnt we have something like this?

[image]

How important is the delay and when can we ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this delay in the feedback loop is important or not depends on:

1. What is the response time of your system?  A system that responds in a time that is on the same order as your delay can develop resonances or oscillations because of that delay. If your delay time is much smaller than the response of the system you'll be safe.
2. What is the slew rate of your input?  A gradual change of input can produce a controlled output even in a system that would become unstable with rapid input changes.

If you can't get your delay time low enough for stable behaviour, then you need to have a more intelligent control loop.  That's where the PID approach becomes useful.

Comment: So lets say if time response of the system is $4e^{-t}$ then the delay must be less than $abs(\frac{d}{dt} 4e^{-t})$

Comment: If the the delay is too high and hardware changes are not an option, then either use a lower bandwidth controller or indeed use a different controller design, such as a [Smith predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_predictor) but do keep in mind that these often do not improve disturbance rejection, similar to the limitations due to [RHP zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3008837/76466).

Comment: PID won't necessarily save you tho, the issue is more fundamental

Answer (score 0):

Yes it matters!

To determine when: if you are okay doing s-plane analysis:

You can approximate the delay into something linear (unity gain with poles and zeros), using technique of *Padé approximant*, for instance.

The simplest approximation of a delay is one pole (LHP) and one zero (RHP). Finer approximations give, for instance, a semicircle of LHP poles around the origin and a semicircle RHP zeros also around the origin. You can see how this creates a problem, since the zeros will draw the root locus into the unstable area, if the gain is turned up too much.

Anyway, your can then apply either Root Locus or Nyquist analysis. Can't do Bode, because the RHP zeros violate the requirement of Bode analysis, that the system be *Minimum Phase*.

There are also crude design heuristics (for certain classes of system, e.g. X poles and Y zeros) where you can substitute a 1-pole response for the delay for design purposes (search the literature)